# Gatsby + Contentful + Netlify - how to render tracedSVG images in production?

Tags: gatsby, netlify, contentful, fluid-images, gatsby-image

I am building a website using **Gatbsy**, **Contentful** CMS and **Netlify**.
It looks great and works locally but I have a problem in production regarding fluid images using the **tracedSVG** option. The Netlify deploy used to work on occasions and as I added more images to the project now breaks constantly with the following errors (not always in the same page):

```
10:53:45 AM: The GraphQL query from /opt/build/repo/src/pages/index.js failed.
10:53:45 AM: Errors:
10:53:45 AM:   VipsJpeg: Corrupt JPEG data: premature end of data segment
10:53:45 AM:   VipsJpeg: out of order read at line 544
10:53:45 AM:   GraphQL request:54:3
10:53:45 AM:   53 | fragment GatsbyContentfulFluid_tracedSVG on ContentfulFluid {
10:53:45 AM:   54 |   tracedSVG
10:53:45 AM:      |   ^
10:53:45 AM:   55 |   aspectRatio
```

or sometimes

```
error
The GraphQL query from /opt/build/repo/src/pages/index.js failed.
Errors: Input file contains unsupported image format
  GraphQL request:40:3
| fragment GatsbyContentfulFluid_tracedSVG on ContentfulFluid {
|   tracedSVG
|   ^
|   aspectRatio
```

and on rare occasions

```
Errors:
  VipsJpeg: Empty input file
```

(this last one not making sense as the images are present in Contentful and a required field of my content model)

As mentioned previously; the GraphQL query retrieving the tracedSVG images from Contentful work locally. My code is as follow:

```
import React from "react"
import { Link, graphql } from "gatsby"
import Img from "gatsby-image"

const IndexPage = ({ data: { allContentfulIndexPage }) => {
  const { myImage } = allContentfulIndexPage.edges[0].node

  return (
    <div>
      {...someIrrelevantCodeToTheQuestion}
      <Img fluid={myImage.fluid}/>
    </div>
  )
}

export default IndexPage

export const query = graphql`
  query IndexPageQuery {
    allContentfulIndexPage {
      edges {
        node {
          myImage {
            fluid {
              ...GatsbyContentfulFluid_tracedSVG
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

By using GraphiQL I found out that locally using `tracedSVG` instead of `...GatsbyContentfulFluid_tracedSVG` also works locally but it crashes just the same in a Production/Netlify environment. I considered using `png` images instead of `jpg` as the errors suggest something wrong with the files themselves although they render fine locally but the equivalent in png size would slow down the site (a jpg image of 100kB is roughly 900kb in png).

Did anyone encounter the same issue regarding `tracedSVG` rendering with jpg images in production and if this is the case how did you solve to stop recurrent crashes? Thank you.

Comment: Pretty sure this is a unresolved bug the problems, is one is that maxHeight and `maxWidth` aren't used in `traceSVG. The logic from fluid should be copied to `traceSVG` even though technically not necessary. Try `fluid(maxWidth: 500, maxHeight: 500)` just to see if it builds. Also I think there is an issue with the memoization of the `tracedSVG`. It memoizes by file name and args, while the crop is set in `fileArgs` parameters.

Comment: Hi @NickC Thanks for your input. I tried with `fluid(maxWidth: 500, maxHeight: 500)` to see if it would resolve the issue and it didn't. The issue appears during the checks of the graphQL queries. I'm still fiddling with different options but haven't found what works yet. It could be an unresolved bug as you mentioned.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's been a month since I posted that question so thought I should post my non-solution but more like a work around in case someone faces the same issue. It seems that `GatsbyContentfulFluid_tracedSVG` is actually broken in production and the bug is unresolved to date.

I simply decided to revert to using a `fluid` solution instead of `tracedSVG` since it works in both development and production environments so having images as

```
<Img
  fluid={node.image.fluid} />
```

and queries as

```
node {
  image {
    fluid {
      ...GatsbyContentfulFluid
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @GBouffard Interesting, same problems here on every other build. I will go and try this next. Any setbacks for this way of doing it with GtasbyContentfulFluid? If I understand right the fluid is used with a maxWidth ```fluid(maxWidth: 613) {
          sizes
          src
          srcSet
        }``` and provides images that automatically responds to different device screen resolutions and width, a smartphone will download much smaller image. Isn't the tracedSvg only for the grey placeholder providing only some ux for slow loading images?

Answer (score 4):

I have also a finding that might be a "non-solution". Seems that when I run the command `gatsby clean` in the terminal for the project and then commit and push a new change or just a fake change into the master, that is then built on Netlify, the error disappears. Suggests it is something cache related.

Comment: I have been using GitHub Codespaces which runs on a VM and see similar behavior. The initial `gatsby develop` will throw warnings/errors but when I modify a file, it rebuilds and executes the queries successfully. I am using Gatsby Cloud and running into this issue, triggering a rebuild and cache clear still doesn't fix it however. ‍♂️